# Postfix, Amavis-new, ClamAV: Permission denied. ERROR

Tags: centos, security, postfix

Error lines in **/var/log/maillog**

```
Sep 22 12:08:20 sun amavis[4493]: (04493-09) (!)run_av (ClamAV-clamd) FAILED - unexpected , output="/var/spool/amavisd/tmp/amavis-20130922T052321-04493-crApLkq5/parts: lstat() failed: Permission denied. ERROR\n"
Sep 22 12:08:20 sun amavis[4493]: (04493-09) (!)ClamAV-clamd av-scanner FAILED: CODE(0x29185c0) unexpected , output="/var/spool/amavisd/tmp/amavis-20130922T052321-04493-crApLkq5/parts: lstat() failed: Permission denied. ERROR\n" at (eval 113) line 897.
Sep 22 12:08:20 sun amavis[4493]: (04493-09) (!)WARN: all primary virus scanners failed, considering backups
```

**Server user and group**

```
# cat /etc/passwd | grep "amavis\|clamav"
clam:x:495:493:Clam Anti Virus Checker:/var/lib/clamav:/sbin/nologin
amavis:x:494:492:User for amavisd-new:/var/spool/amavisd:/sbin/nologin
# id amavis
uid=494(amavis) gid=492(amavis) groups=492(amavis),493(clam)
# id clam
uid=495(clam) gid=493(clam) groups=493(clam),492(amavis)
```

**Services**

> chkconfig --list | grep "amavisd\|clamd\|spamassassin"

```
amavisd         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:off   5:off   6:off
clamd           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:off   5:on    6:off
clamd.amavisd   0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:off   5:off   6:off
spamassassin    0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:off   5:off   6:off
```

**/etc/clamd.conf**

```
LocalSocket /var/run/clamav/clamd.sock
LocalSocketGroup amavis
User clam
```

**/etc/amavisd.conf**

```
### http://www.clamav.net/
['ClamAV-clamd',
  \&ask_daemon, ["CONTSCAN {}\n", "/var/run/clamav/clamd.sock"],
  qr/\bOK$/, qr/\bFOUND$/,
  qr/^.*?: (?!Infected Archive)(.*) FOUND$/ ],
# # NOTE: run clamd under the same user as amavisd, or run it under its own
# #   uid such as clamav, add user clamav to the amavis group, and then add
# #   AllowSupplementaryGroups to clamd.conf;
# # NOTE: match socket name (LocalSocket) in clamav.conf to the socket name in
# #   this entry; when running chrooted one may prefer socket "$MYHOME/clamd".
```

**/etc/postfix/master.cf**

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
amavisfeed unix    -       -       n        -      2     lmtp
    -o lmtp_data_done_timeout=1200
    -o lmtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
    -o max_use=20

# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n    -       n       -       -     smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
    -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
    -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
    -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
    -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
    -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
    -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters,no_address_mappings
    -o local_header_rewrite_clients=
    -o smtpd_milters=
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
```

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
content_filter=amavisfeed:[127.0.0.1]:10024
```

**ls /var/spool/amavisd/tmp/**

```
drwxr-x---. 3 amavis amavis 4096 Sep 23 15:00 amavis-20130923T150035-15730-hgztdUJP
drwxr-x---. 3 amavis amavis 4096 Sep 23 15:12 amavis-20130923T151205-16266-HUEzwmIf
```

**ls /var/spool/amavisd/ -l**

```
srwxr-x---. 1 amavis amavis    0 Sep 23 04:36 amavisd.sock
drwx------. 2 amavis amavis 4096 Sep 23 04:36 db
drwx------. 2 amavis amavis 4096 Feb 22  2013 quarantine
drwx------. 4 amavis amavis 4096 Sep 23 18:14 tmp
```

Answer (score 5):

This looks to be a permissions problem with this directory:

```
/var/spool/amavisd/tmp/
```

Based on the log messages it looks like the user `amavis` does not have access to this directory.

Comment: Thx @slm. I checked and added result screen below the question.

Comment: I removed all (ClamAV, Amavis-new, Spamassassin). It were from EPEL Repository. **I installed from RPMForge Repository. And everything is fine now**

Answer (score 4):

As the comment you made mentions, RPMForge will work, but is not necessarily the proper way to fix the issue since RPMForge does not conform to the same standards as EPEL.

The problem with EPEL is that the "clam" user does not have access to the amavis folders. To get this to work with EPEL is pretty staight forward:

```
usermod -a -G amavis clam
chmod g+rx /var/spool/amavisd/tmp
```

This ads clam to the amavis group, then gives access to the amavis group to the tmp directory.